# Facebook SDK '4.+' suddenly throws import error, things glow in red - Android Studio (2.0)

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, gradle, facebook-sdk-4.0

While testing my app, I had no problems with the Facebook SDK. Suddenly today, every Facebook imports are glowing in red.

I have cleared my project, rebuilt it several times, restarted Android Studio but nothing has changed.

What should I do?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: try this sdk for facebook .. compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.11.0'

Comment: Thanks man, it works now. What could be wrong with the '4.+'?

Comment: it is not working some time.....!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.11.0'
}
```